# How to Pause and resume Jenkins Build

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a power shell job in Jenkins that copies code to multiple servers. Some times, script might not reach a server and it breaks the build. When i remove the server from my list and resume the build, it starts from step 1 (Server 1). Is there any way in Jenkins to pause the build at particular step and have user resume it from where it stopped.

Please let me know.

Comment: I haven't heard of any features like this, but have you checked for Jenkins plugins?

Comment: Yes, I checked and haven't found anything that fits my requirements.

Comment: I am not sure who will create such plugin! Sorry that it sounds weird to me.
Usually it should be handled by the script itself.

Comment: Could you use the workflow plug in for this? I think that enables restarting a particular build step.

Comment: @Petrik you are talking about checkpoints that are the part of Jenkins Enterprise version of Pipeline (former Workkflow).

Comment: @izzekil Yeah I think I am. I didn't realise it was part of the enterprise version :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired behavior it with [Jenkins Pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md). Below is the code draft that should explain my idea.

```
def remoteServers = [ipaddr1, ipaddr2,...] // define all remote hosts servers in the groovy code
for (int i=0; i<remoteServers.size(); i++) { // c-style loop is to avoid JENKINS-26481
    def ip = remoteServers[i]
    try {
        bat "your script here" // ip should be passed as a parameter
                              // or interpolated right within the inlined script
    catch {
        input "Retry for ${ip}?" // This will pause the build waiting for user action
        i-- // repeat the iteration
    }
}
```

However this does not allow to pause build at arbitrary moment (technically it could).